# C#: Closing a process/window with its child window, only closes the child and left main window inaccessible

Tags: c#, windows

i have a problem closing a process (a window) which spawns a child window.

- I start the process (the parent window) via: **System.Diagnostics.Process.Start**
- When the process is started it spawns another window by itself (the child window)
- Both windows are listed in the Windows Task Manager in the Process tab, under the same name when clicking on the arrow symbol to expand
- The Details tab just shows one entry for the process
- When manually closing the child window (by clicking on the x-symbol) the main window remains
- When manually closing the parent window, the child window also closes

My problem is, when tying to close **both** windows, by simly calling `process.CloseMainWindow(); process.Close();` just the child window is closed and the parent window remains. At this point i found no way to also close the remaining parent window.
What can i do? (btw. `process.Refresh();` does not work).

edit: i have noticed that just calling `process.Kill();` closes both windows reliably.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/obtaining-ui-automation-elements